# Different ways to ask

Tags: грамматика, перевод, выбор-слова

There appear to be three different words in Russian for the English word 'to ask': спрашивать, просить, and задавать.  Are these synonyms, and if not, how are they different?

Comment: "Задавать" part is covered already by Nikolay's answer, the rest is covered in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

**спрашивать:** "ask" as in inquire.

**просить:** "ask" as in politely or humbly request.

**задавать:** is not, on its own, a translation of "to ask", but you're clearly thinking of the phrase **задавать вопрос**, "pose a question". It's a little more formal and it's also what you use when you don't specify what the question is (as in "I asked you a question").